# Postgres: query for a specific date on a timestampz returns no data while I can see the data in my postgres client

Tags: postgresql

I'm very new at postgres and I've been googling this for about 1h before posting here.

Hopefully, you can help me with this probably trivial issue.

I have a database `LTC` that was created with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE LTC (
       id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       time     timestamptz,
       side     CHAR(4),
       price    REAL,
       v        REAL,
       n        INT
    );
```

I want to query to get all the data for time='2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z' (ISO string from javascript). I know there are over a hundred lines of data in the database for that time, i see it in my postgres client.

Here is the query I'm doing:

```
select * from LTC where time = '2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamptz
```

Why am I getting no results?

---

*Edit*:

Still unsure why it wasn't working, but I wrote a work-around that does:

In JavaScript:

```
var date    = new Date('2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z').toISOString(); // actual time passed as parameter in my function, hard-coded for the example
var reg     = new RegExp("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\.[0-9]*Z","gmi");
var start   = date.replace(reg, function(match,year,month,day,hour,min,sec,ms) {
    return year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+hour+':'+min+':00.000Z';
});
var end     = date.replace(reg, function(match,year,month,day,hour,min,sec,ms) {
    var min = parseInt(min)+1;
    if (min<=9) {
        min = '0'+min;
    }
    return year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+hour+':'+min+':00.000Z';
});

var query   = "select * from LTC where time >= '"+start+"'::timestamptz and time < '"+end+"'::timestamptz"; // This works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `date_trunc('second',timestamp)` on both to ensure that numerical precision is not what is throwing you off.  There may be additional decimal places that are not being shown by your client and throwing off the equality.

The other possible solution is giving a range (`between x and y`) to avoid the numerical equality issue.

It would be easier for us to help if you can get an exact copy of the data being represented (using `pg_dump` perhaps, if you are familiar) so that we can test with the data that you are using.

The final thing you may want to check is explicitly stating the time zones that you are referencing.  I generally use `timestamp without time zone` to avoid this issue, but auto-setting time zones to different values may be throwing you off as well.  A good way to test is by selecting the two values, something like

```
select *, l.time = p.ts as test
from LTC l, (select '2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamptz as ts) p
;
```

**EDIT:**

I have built a test to try to reproduce your behavior:

```
CREATE TABLE LTC (
 id serial
 , time timestamptz
 );

 INSERT INTO LTC (time)
 values ('2017-08-12T03:58:26.56312345'::timestamptz)
 returning *;

 select *
 from LTC 
 where time = '2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamptz
 ;

 select *, l.time = p.ts as test
from LTC l, (select '2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamptz as ts) p
;
```

What I get here is actually:

```
1;"2017-08-12 03:58:26.563123-04";"2017-08-11 23:58:26.563-04";f
```

Hopefully you can see what is happening - the `'2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamptz` is being interpreted as a UTC time and then converted to my time zone (UTC-04), so what is being compared is actually a different *date* altogether!  In the future, showing this type of equality side-by-side is a great way to test that you are executing what you think you are (especially with dates / times where auto-conversion happens often).

Comment: Still no idea why it wasn't working, but I tried your range solution and it solved the issue. I posted the JS code to generate the query.

Comment: Ouch.  That's a painful JS script!  If all you need is minute-precision, maybe try this as an alternative (logic on the DB side): `select *
from LTC
where date_trunc('minute',time::timestamp) = date_trunc('minute','2017-08-12T03:58:26.563Z'::timestamp);`.  Casting to `timestamp` seems to resolve some of the auto-conversion issues I was having with using `timestamptz`, if you are not passing time-zone explicitly, at least.